# My checkbox is not saving data in wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress, function, checkbox, save

I know there are some other topics with this question, but they all have their respective coding. With mine, i do understand how to change to checklists or others.
The one problems is that the data does not save, i mean, i click the checkbox square and save the post but when it reloads there are no checkboxs saved. All this happens in wordpress.

This is my checkbox code in functions.php of wordpress

```
function prfx_custom_meta() {
add_meta_box( 'prfx_meta', __( 'Meta Box Title', 'prfx-textdomain' ), 'prfx_meta_callback', 'post' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'prfx_custom_meta' );

function prfx_meta_callback( $post ) {
wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'prfx_nonce' );
$prfx_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
?>

<p>
<span class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e( 'Example Checkbox Input', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></span>
<div class="prfx-row-content">
    <label for="meta-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="meta-checkbox" id="meta-checkbox" value="yes" <? php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-checkbox'] ) ) checked( 

$prfx_stored_meta['meta-checkbox'][0], 'yes' ); ?> />
        <?php _e( 'Checkbox label', 'prfx-textdomain' )?>
    </label>
    <label for="meta-checkbox-two">
        <input type="checkbox" name="meta-checkbox-two" id="meta-checkbox-two" value="yes" <?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-checkbox-two'] ) ) checked( 

$prfx_stored_meta['meta-checkbox-two'][0], 'yes' ); ?> />
        <?php _e( 'Another checkbox', 'prfx-textdomain' )?>
    </label>
</div>
```

And after that comes the data save function that is not working properly:

```
   <?php
}

function prfx_meta_save( $post_id ) {

// Checks save status
$is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
$is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
$is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'prfx_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'prfx_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

// Exits script depending on save status
if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
    return;
}

// Checks for input and sanitizes/saves if needed
if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-text' ] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-text', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'meta-text' ]    ) );
}

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'prfx_meta_save' );

?>
```

EDIT:

I have changed the save data to this, because there as andrewsi said, there was nothing dealing with meta-checkbox and meta-checkbox-two.

```
 <?php
}

function prfx_meta_save( $post_id ) {

// Checks save status
$is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
$is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
$is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'prfx_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[   'prfx_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

// Exits script depending on save status
if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
    return;
}

// Checks for input and sanitizes/saves if needed
if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-checkbox' ] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-checkbox', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'meta-checkbox' ] ));
}

if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-checkbox-two' ] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-checkbox-two', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'meta-checkbox-two' ] ));
}

}
 add_action( 'save_post', 'prfx_meta_save' );
```

The problem now is that i can't uncheck the checkbox; i mean, i check the box and save the post, when the edit post reloads i uncheck the checkbox and save the post again, but at reload the checkbox will stay checked. ¿Why?

Comment: I might be missing something, but there's nothing in your save code that deals with `meta-checkbox` or `meta-checkbox-two`

Comment: You are right @andrewsi edited, but new problem...